# How to format a SSRS field with 2-digits of procession when the data is a mix of formats

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have data from a Stored Procedure that looks like this and needs to display on my report with 2-digits of precision. The data is all NVARCHAR but there is a mix of rows that looks numeric or says 'Max'.

[image]

How do I display only 2 digits of precision? I tried the following which works great on the numeric looking data but errors on 'Max'.

```
=FormatNumber(Fields!TBS.Value, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an IIF to determine if the value is a number and IIF so, format it.

```
=IIF(ISNUMERIC(Fields!TBS.Value), FormatNumber(Fields!TBS.Value, 2), Fields!TBS.Value)
```

IsNumeric:

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an expression can be
>   evaluated as a number.

MS SSRS Description